# How to calculate the spectral radius of $A^TA$ where the matrix $A$ is not symmetric but has same diagonal elements

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-radius

If the matrix $A$ contains only real values and is also symmetric, then the spectral radius of $A^TA$ is:

$$ \rho(A^TA)= (|\lambda|_{max})^2 \tag1$$

where $|\lambda|_{max}$ is the maximum absolute eigenvalue of matrix $A$. In my case, I am trying to find the spectral radius of $A^TA$ where $A$ is not symmetric. Is there any way I can do this without actually multiplying $A^T$ and $A$? The format of $A$ is quite big, so it is not very practical. Note that the elements of any of its diagonals are the same. For example:

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & 0 & c & 0 \\
d & a & b & 0 & c \\
0 & d & a & b & 0 \\
e & 0 & d & a & b \\
0 & e & 0 & d & a
\end{bmatrix}
\tag 2$$

Comment: You may try to search the web for “singular values of Toeplitz matrix” or “spectral norm of Toeplitz matrix”.

Comment: Thanks for the hint :D